# java: check if any element in array 1 is present in array 2

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am fairly new to java streams and wonder whether there is an easy solution using java streams to check if any element in array 1 is also present in array 2

example:

```
array1 = ["banana","apple","cat"]
array2 = ["toast","bread","pizza","banana"]
--> return true

array1 = ["banana","apple","cat"]
array2 = ["toast","bread","pizza"]
--> return false
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything with code that you can show us?

Answer (score 4):

Just use Collections.disjoint. This method checks if any elements of the both arrays are common.

```
Collections.disjoint(Arrays.asList(array1), Arrays.asList(array2))
```

Comment: 1+; what I really don't like about `disjoint` is that the method parameters are declared using wildcards, as such I can call it with `Collections.disjoint(List.of(""), List.of(1));` - though `Integer` and `String` are completely un-related, this will still compile.

Comment: @Eugene Note, though, that `disjoint` is allowed to throw a `ClassCastException` “if one collection contains an element that is of a type which is ineligible for the other collection.” (on my Java 9 it didn’t in your example).

Comment: @OleV.V. to be honest I am a bit confused now, because I though that if I declare a method like `static <T, U extends T> boolean disjoint(List<T> left, List<U> right) {
        return false;
    }` and use it as : `disjoint(List.of(""), List.of(1));` this would not compile, but to my surprise, it does. One the other hand `List<String> strings = List.of("");
        disjoint(strings, List.of(1));` this does not. it seems like the compiler infers `List.of("")` to a type that we can't normally create

Comment: Curious, right, though we’re digressing. In the former example my Eclipse infers `List<Serializable>` for `List.of("")` and `List<Integer>` for `List.of(1)`, so that compiles. In the latter example you specify `List<String>`, so that doesn’t compile. We can of course control the type, for example `List.<Object>of("")`.

Comment: @OleV.V. very interesting that Eclipse shows you the inferred type, I've tried `javac --debug=verboseResolution=deferred-inference ...`, but I don't get a clear picture of what `List.of("")` is inferred to.

Comment: @Eugene that’s *target type inference* at work. In your nested method invocation, the constraints placed at your `disjoint` method force the compiler to find compatible types for both `List.of` invocations, so it ends up at `INT#2 extends Object,Serializable,Comparable<?>` though these common interfaces are just noise, as the method would also be applicable if the only common type was `Object`.

Comment: @Holger that makes sense, agreed. but I really wish the compiler would show me the inferred types here, still. cause I can't make sense of `INT#1..` and `INT#2...`

Comment: @Eugene `INT#1` etc. are just generated names for INTernal type variables, which allows to refer to them in the bounds of other inferred types.

Comment: @Holger is it safe to think than that the inferred types are something like : `INT#1 extends Object & Serializable & Comparable<? extends INT#2> & Constable & ConstantDesc`?

Comment: @Eugene “safe” in what regard?

Comment: @Holger sorry, I should have explicitly mention that the other user involved in this discussion said that eclipse in this case inferred the types to `List<Serializable>` (I assume it's actually `List<? extends Serializable>`); so _safe_ in this way would actually be safe for me to understand, since I can't tell who is right here, eclipse or `javac`; because it seems that `javac` infers a very weird type. I hope I make some sense here

Comment: @Eugene in case of Eclipse, I assume, it’s what the IDE showed in the tool-tip, which tends to (over-)simplify. However, it’s kind of justified, as the longer signature doesn’t matter anyway, all that matters, is, that the compiler accepted the construct and after type erasure, the remaining type is indeed `Serializable`, which is the only type which may have an effect on the runtime, e.g., if you used `disjoint(Arrays.asList(""), List.of(1))` with your `disjoint` method, it truly creates a `Serializable[]` array for the varargs method.

Answer (score 1):

I think this works for you. However, I had to convert the second array to a set check if element exists in an array. I think that's more intuitive than a for loop iteration.

```java
String[] arr1 = new String[]{"a", "b"};
String[] arr2 = new String[]{"a", "d"};
Set<String> strings = Set.of(arr2);
boolean result = Stream.of(arr1).anyMatch(strings::contains);
```

Comment: you could create a `Set` for faster look-ups, since java-9 there is that one single method call `Set::of`, in java-8 - you would still need to do `new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(array))`